# How to add custom translation to ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angular-translate

Official docs only showcase picking from existing translations. I tried to use code used by ui-grid itself, but it wont work for me for whatever reason:

```js
(function () {
angular.module('ui.grid').config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('i18nService', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    $delegate.add('pl', {
          groupPanel: {
            description: 'Przeciągnij nagłówek kolumny tutaj, aby pogrupować według niej.'
          },
          sort: {
            ascending: 'Sortuj rosnąco',
            descending: 'Sortuj malejąco',
            remove: 'Wyłącz sortowanie'
          },
        }
      });
      return $delegate;
    }]);
  }]);
})();
```

What is proper way to achieve above goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being ui-grid an open source project, the proper way to add a non existing language would be to add it to the source and ask the team to accept your edits.

If you're not accustomed to the way the project works you can take a look at these docs:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/FIRST_TIMER.md

As to why your code is not working, I don't know :D because it's actually working! I copied it into [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NMjlGpVfAOajGOpSySMO?p=preview) and it's just right (beware that pl is the last one inside the selection list since we add it in the js code after the library got instantiated).

Note that I had to remove the curly bracket under the line:

```
... definitions of translation goes here
```

Comment: Sadly it do not work. Yes `groupPanel.description` will be translated by `i18nService`, but drop-down menus on grid remain untranslated :( To highlight issue I added 2 translations. First works as expected. Second that should show app on column drop-down sort menu do not.

Comment: OK. I found bug. ui-grid wont rerender header drop-down on language change. So I need to specify `pl` **before** ui-grid is rendered for the first time.

Comment: I digged some more. ui-grid.js will work with this plunkr but ui-grid.min.js wont :| So I'm taking "mark as answer" back

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to make it work with minification cause you have no way to know the minified names. At this point you should really create a Pull Request on github.

Comment: Yes. Yes. Done it :P Let me guess. You are contributor/author of ui-grid?

Comment: Yes, but I'm relatively new to it!